# Game sound design studies?

Tags: sound-design, gameaudio, education

I'm currently doing a music tech course in London and looking for further education. I want to study sound design for games and movies but I'm not sure which are the best universities to consider. If someone could offer advise that would be great, they need to be in London or easily accessible by train from London.

Comment: If you want to go into the games industry I would definitely consider further study.  Of the 42 people I know who work in sound for EA, 38 have formal qualifications ranging from diplomas through to masters degrees, the subjects studied were predominantly sound design/production or music.

Answer (score 2):

For games you can consider joining a game development team/company instead of enrolling in the university. Choose small ones so you can be directly involving and talking with senior sound designers there.

Comment: Not only is this to be considered, but is also a very advisable advice. One is not going to become employed in this field with a certification, but with people to work with and a portfolio of past work. Not many schools are able to offer this kind of real world experience. 

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure which are the best universities to consider.

I'd say none, because I think most formal courses in sound are either about studying trivial BS or a valuable business for its staff, or both. You can do so much more, if you just have a look and a go at it yourself, because there's really nothing preventing one from self-studying and it's also a rather non-painful process (even more so when you can use the best resources and the most motivating practices you can find), because the field is simple and concise in technical practice as well as in theory.

Now if you'd like to do something formally, then you could probably try applying here: http://nftsfilm-tv.ac.uk/our-courses/diploma/sound-recording-film-television, as it's decently appreciated by industry professionals. For game audio I'd probably look at http://school.videogameaudio.com/apply/ as it's an online course and covers only the things that are particularly different in game audio compared to linear media. For a different take on game audio, I'd suggest computer science / IT over sound production courses.

Answer (score 0):

WOuld probaly second what @Internet Human said, you will pay thousands to get MAYBE a handful of courses tailored to you. For (I believe) less that 300 USD you can get a fairly in-depth (based on things that I've heard) learning experience from video game audio school at least to get a start. Fmod has a wealth of tutorial videos up on that program as well.